# Creating a Wrapper for RestKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit, objective-c-blocks, grand-central-dispatch

I am trying to write a wrapper for `RestKit`, so that all requests call one function which in turn would trigger a request via `RestKit`.

Here's what I have so far:

A function would call my wrapper as follows:

NSDictionary *response = [Wrappers sendRequestWithURLString:url method:@"GET"];

And my wrapper methods:

```
+ (NSDictionary *)sendRequestWithURLString:(NSString *)request method:(NSString *)method
{    
    RKRequestDidFailLoadWithErrorBlock failBlock;

    if ([method isEqualToString:@"GET"])
        return [self sendGETRequestWithURLString:request withFailBlock:failBlock];

    else if ([method isEqualToString:@"POST"])
        return [self sendPOSTRequestWithURLString:request withFailBlock:failBlock];

    return nil;
}




   + (NSDictionary *)sendGETRequestWithURLString:(NSString *)request withFailBlock:(RKRequestDidFailLoadWithErrorBlock)failBlock {

        RKObjectManager *manager = [RKObjectManager sharedManager];

        __block NSDictionary *responseDictionary;

        [manager loadObjectsAtResourcePath:request usingBlock:^(RKObjectLoader *loader) {

            loader.onDidLoadResponse = ^(RKResponse *response) {

                [self fireErrorBlock:failBlock onErrorInResponse:response];

                RKJSONParserJSONKit *parser = [RKJSONParserJSONKit new]; 
                responseDictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:[parser objectFromString:[response bodyAsString] error:nil]];
            };
        }];

        return responseDictionary;
    }

+ (void)fireErrorBlock:(RKRequestDidFailLoadWithErrorBlock)failBlock onErrorInResponse:(RKResponse *)response {

    if (![response isOK]) {

        id parsedResponse = [response parsedBody:NULL];
        NSString *errorText = nil;

        if ([parsedResponse isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
            errorText = [parsedResponse objectForKey:@"error"];
        }

        if (errorText)
            failBlock([self errorWithMessage:errorText code:[response statusCode]]);
    }
}

+ (NSError *)errorWithMessage:(NSString *)errorText code:(NSUInteger)statusCode {

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" 
                                                    message:@"Please make sure you are connected to WiFi or 3G." 
                                                   delegate:nil
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];

    return nil;
}
```

The problem here is when `responseDictionary` returns, the value is nil since `onDidLoadResponse` would not have processed yet as it runs concurrently.

In this case, what would be the best approach in setting `responseDictionary`? I'm trying to avoid calling a setter method of another class. In this case, is my only option using delegates, which defeats the whole purpose of creating a wrapper class since RestKit calls require usage of delegate methods to return the response?

Would I be able to pass my wrapper a `success` block which would update some local ivar? How would I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pass a success block as you have said. Here is an example of how to do that:

.h

```
typedef void (^kServiceCompleteBlock)(NSDictionary* responseDictionary);

...
+ (NSDictionary *)sendGETRequestWithURLString:(NSString *)request withFailBlock:(RKRequestDidFailLoadWithErrorBlock)failBlock completion: (kServiceCompleteBlock) completion ;

...
```

.m

```
+ (NSDictionary *)sendGETRequestWithURLString:(NSString *)request withFailBlock:(RKRequestDidFailLoadWithErrorBlock)failBlock completion: (kServiceCompleteBlock) completion {

...

loader.onDidLoadResponse = ^(RKResponse *response) {

            [self fireErrorBlock:failBlock onErrorInResponse:response];

            RKJSONParserJSONKit *parser = [RKJSONParserJSONKit new]; 
            responseDictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:[parser objectFromString:[response bodyAsString] error:nil]];

            if( completion )
               completion(responseDictionary);
        };

...

}
```

However, let me warn you of a potential design flaw. You should design your app so that the UI is driven by your data and not your web service. This means your UI should automatically update when your data model is updated and not when your web service returns. Be careful how  you use this response dictionary. If it is to update UI then you are running down a dangerous road.

Comment: To address your warning, I will have my UI update from my Core Data data. I will need to work out some animation to keep updating it seamlessly I assume.

Comment: AFNetworking and RestKit are two completely different things. I recommend them both for their own purpose.

Comment: For pure networking download, does AFNetworking have the advantage over RestKit?